# Why does running a python script (.py file) in my Mac Terminal return a "quote>"?

Tags: terminal, python, macos

Searched around for a while for an answer to this. Recently whenever I try to run a python script I've written from my Terminal all I get back is 'quote>' with every subsequent line no matter what I do also returning that. Couldn't find another example of this for some reason so just trying to figure out what janky thing I did to cause this.
[image]

Comment: Well, show us exactly what you ran, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have a single quote. Rename the file to collatz.py with the `mv collatz\'s.py collatz.py` then run the command again.

Comment: Thanks for that, solved my problem immediately, knew something was off

Comment: No problemo. In the future avoid using these characters: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-the-bash/1565923472/ch01s09.html in filenames and you should be able to avoid funky problems like this.